# Java(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE) Remove users from Combo box on EXIT?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to remove a user from a combo box once he decides to exit the main Frame. Does anyone have an idea how I can possibly detect it? I have got some other buttons which detect when a new user logs in or logs out and respectively they are removed from the combo box, but I can't figure how to get it working when a user just exits the main Frame.

Thank you in advance!
Happy Holidays!

***EDIT***

**WindowAdapter** allows overriding whatever method related to the frame you may need.
This answers my question! Thanks everyone!

Comment: Er... if the application is exiting, how are you planning on modifying a combobox in it?

Comment: @Powerlord, well, yeah. How do I detect that? is there any convenient way of doing it?

Comment: Don't use EXIT_ON_CLOSE. Use a WindowListener and do whatever you want, then System.exit() in the windowClosing() method.